# Finding inverse matrix $(X'X)^{-1}$ with $X$ as design matrix

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

I'm relatively new to all this and I am trying to figure out how I can derive the matrix $(X'X)^{-1}$ when I have given $x_1, x_2, x_3$ and $y$. $X$ is the design matrix in that case but not sure how I can come up with the $(X'X)^{-1}$?

Comment: Are you aware of the definition of the transpose, matrix products, and matrix inversion?  If you know the design matrix (that is, the matrix without y and with a column fo ones for an intercept) then the quantity you're asking for should be straight forward to compute (if not by hand then with the help of a computer)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, to be honest, the data for y,x1 and so forth are in a dataset or do you mean in general the definition of what a transpose etc matrix is?

Comment: This is the stuff of linear algebra.  Consult your favorite text or [search the Web](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=matrix+inversion+algorithm). Regardless, you usually don't want to invert this matrix directly.  Look up "QR decomposition" (this time in a linear algebra text oriented towards numerical algorithms).